# Is it possible to copy mounted database without RMAN?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I need to make a copy of production database for development. For some reason I can't use RMAN. My question is: can I copy standby database while its in mounted state and recovery is canceled? Of course I can shut it down to make a "cold backup", but I do not want to lose time for manually copying new archive logs (and I don't have enough space on primary for keeping them for a long time).

The procedure was fine until today. After a few hours I got this:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gtar: owfin_d/owfin_d06.dbf: file changed as we read it.
```

It is strange because timestamps on all db files shows the time when I canceled standby recovery.

**UPD** After a long time I found the problem. For some reason a scrip on cron schedule changes file permissions and tar responds with "file changed as we read it".

Comment: You can't afford the normal `begin backup/end backup` procedure?

Comment: Yep. I can't do it on primary and standby throws error "Database not opened".

Comment: why cant you use rman on primary? backup prohibited by policy?

Comment: Interesting. I'm quite sure that nothing at all should write to datafiles in your situation. How did you make sure "recovery is canceled"?

Comment: @Raj I must do backups on standby because of disk performance.

Comment: @kubanczyk I'm not quite sure. All I know is that tar said "file changed" so the bash script exited. Maybe its a bug in Solaris's tar.

Comment: @miracle173 Oh, sorry. Will do in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change file's permissions during copy operation, tar will throw "file changes as we read it".